# On Textbox focus open Popup AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a textbox in AngularJs form. Currently I am using ng-change to open a modal pop-up. However, I would like to open the pop-up, when the focus hits the textbox. Below is the current code:

```
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
       <div class="input-group col-md-6">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
          </span>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Search the group" ng-model="searchDatalocation" ng-change="searchUsers()" name="searchValue">
         </div>
      </div>    

<span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.searchValue.$error.required">Data is required</span>
```

How to open pop-up on focus? Is there any other event which can be used other than ng-change?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `ng-focus="searchUsers()"`  instead of `ng-change="searchUsers()"`